# Change page with react-router-dom in React class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am currently stuck without getting errors, and I can not figure out what to try next.

I have an App.js which contains the standard page switching, which works:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <nav>
        <Link to="/googlesearch">
          <i className="material-icons">search</i>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/createUser">
          <i className="material-icons">add</i>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/">
          <i className="material-icons">home</i>
        </Link>
      </nav>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/create" element={<Create />} />
        <Route path="/createUser" element={<CreateUser />} />
        <Route path="/googlesearch" element={<GoogleSearch />} />
        <Route path="/:id" element={<Update />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```

When I click my googlesearch, I correctly move to my google search page:

```
function GoogleSearch() {
  return (
    <div className="main-wrapper">
      <MyGoogleMap />
    </div>
  );
}
export default GoogleSearch
```

Which renders my google maps component.
Here, I have the integrations figured out, and when I make my location search using the Google `DistanceMatrixService`, I trigger the callback, confirmed by successful console.logs.

Currently, it looks like this:

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
...
...
Render() {
   return(
       <Wrapper>
           ...
           <div>
               <DistanceMatrixService
                   options={{  
                   origins: [autocompletedplace['formatted_address']],
                   destinations: destinations, 
                   travelMode: "DRIVING",
                   }}
                   callback = {(response) => { return(<Navigate to="/" />)}}
               />
           </div>
        </Wrapper>
    );
}
```

I have tried `Navigate` to "/pages/Home", just for a full path attempt.
The current path I am trying to navigate away from is: `"/pages/GoogleSearch"`

I am currently getting no errors in the console, but my page does not change.
So, how do I change the page to a different one, and pass destinations and my response to this new page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `Navigate` only works inside JSX. In non-JSX parts, the idea is to use [useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate), but it only works inside a functional component. Since your component is a class component, you can do this:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
export default class ClassComponentName extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // others states
      redirectToHome: false,
    };
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.redirectToHome) {
      return <Navigate to="/" />;
    }
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        {/* ... */}
        <div>
          <DistanceMatrixService
            options={{
              origins: [autocompletedplace["formatted_address"]],
              destinations: destinations,
              travelMode: "DRIVING",
            }}
            callback={(response) => {
              this.setState({ ...this.state, redirectToHome: true });
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I see! While I can't use the constructor, it breaks everything for some reason I have yet to determine, simply using the part you wrote in the render brackets works!
Thanks alot. I presume the constructor is for exporting the variables? Is there a way around this? I've used constructors in my other components to move data from parents to child, but this data needs to move page, so I'm not sure if there's a different approach.
But, regardless, the page switch works now, so at least the problem has shifted. I assume that counts as a "problem solved" :)

Comment: For the constructor make sure you have `extends Component` and you have imported `Component` as I did.

Comment: Yea, I does; "class MyGoogleMap extends Component {"
Honestly, the problem is it's a copied piece of code from a "how to setup google maps", and modified to my needs, so I'm not entirely sure of everything going on, which means I can't tell what is actually breaking. Which is of course on me. 
I think it breaks however, because imported props from child scripts interfere